# How to change background color of PrimeNg's Sidebar

Tags: html, angular, sass, primeng

I'm using Sidebar component of PrimeNg 14. By default the background color is white. I want it to be red or anything other than white. I followed the documentation for theming also. Either I'm doing it wrong or something else is required. Please have a look.

**HTML:**

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display">
  Sample comtent. <br> Navigation tabs will go here
  <ol>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>contact</li>
    <li>about us</li>
    <li>other controls</li>
  </ol>
</p-sidebar>
```

I tried this:

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" [style]="{background: 'rgb(33,3,63);'}">
...
```

also this:

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" styleClass="p-sidebar-sm">
```

with

```
.p-sidebar-sm {
  background: rgb(33,3,63);
}
```

also I tried ng deep scoping:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-sidebar-sm {
    .p-sidebar-sm {
        background: rgb(33,3,63);
    }
}
```

But still no change in color. Please pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `PrimeNg theming` to customize color.

If not, just override `bachground` of `p-sidebar` in **style.css**

**style.css**

```
.p-sidebar {
  background: rgb(33, 3, 63) !important;
}
```